# multiple order by Is it possible to bring the latest (only one) article by module id ordered by date? EXAMPLE

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have this query where I want to get the newest and latest articles from a complex join while 
ordering by module.

My question for the stackoverflow gurus is the following.

**Is it possible to bring the latest (only one) article by module id ordered by date?**

```
SELECT *
FROM articles Article
LEFT JOIN sources Source ON Article.source_id = Source.id
RIGHT JOIN app_sources asrc ON asrc.source_id = Source.id
/*GROUP BY asrc.module*/ -> if I enable this i get only one but no order by date
ORDER BY asrc.module ASC, Article.published_at DESC
```

This is my first question I hope I formatted it correctly!
Thanks so much

Currently is like this (2k results)

```
published_at    title   module
2012-08-22 12:16:41 |   Archos Gen10: Tablet Productivity | 1
2012-08-22 12:13:22 | Vail Resorts Ski App Gets Racing With Lindsey Vonn |  1
2012-08-22 11:58:06 | The Internet a Decade Later [INFOGRAPHIC] |   1
```

I would want it like this

```
published_at    title   module
2012-08-15 14:37:40 | The Air Force’s New Ultra-Fast Jet Has an Epic Fai... | 1
2012-01-13 16:17:51 | Canada’s Helium Digital shows us the thinnest iPad... | 2
2012-01-13 14:40:14 | ESPN Feels Lonely: A Chat Regarding ESPN’s Role In... | 3
```

Comment: I'm a little confused with exactly what you're trying to do... could you provide some sample data and desired result?

Comment: now I've added an example.
Thanks

Comment: seeing the table structures would be very helpful, even better create a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with sample data, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your table structures, a lot of this is going to be guesswork.  But it seems like you will need to incorporate a `MAX()` on the `published_at` field.

Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT max(published_at) maxDate, source_id
    FROM articles
    GROUP BY source_id
) Article
LEFT JOIN sources Source 
    ON Article.source_id = Source.id
LEFT JOIN app_sources asrc 
    ON Source.id = asrc.source_id
ORDER BY asrc.module ASC, Article.maxDate DESC
```

You will need to provide more details if you want a more definitive answer.

Comment: you are a SQL god. Thanks so much!